# getDerivedStateFromProps called everytime when local state change

Tags: reactjs, getderivedstatefromprops

Currently I am setting `ownUpdate: true` state when we are changing state from same component and check it in getDerivedStateFromProps accordingly. Below is the code I am using in my component. Can anyone suggest better way of doing this. Thanks in advance.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        expanded: props.expanded,
        ownUpdate: false
    }
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (state.ownUpdate) {
        return {
            expanded: state.expanded,
            ownUpdate: false
        };
    } else if (props.expanded !== state.expanded) {
        return {
            expanded: props.expanded
        };
    }
    return null;
}

toggle() {
    this.props. onAfterPress(this.state.expanded, this.props.index);
    this.setState({
        expanded: !this.state.expanded,
        ownUpdate: true
    })
}
```

Comment: You have a miss spelled onAfterPress try correcting it?

Comment: @BrendanPower: Thanks but this is not the issue. I have corrected now.